# Какой полиморфизм считается полиморфизмом

Tags: ооп, терминология

Существует такая проблема, что разные люди-программисты считают за полиморфизм совершенно разные понятия. Покопавшись в теме я понял, что полиморфизмов есть несколько.

Мне понравилось как разные полиморфизмы описываются в
[этом комментарии](https://toster.ru/q/319480) он описывает ситуацию наиболее кратко и понятно. На [вики](http://wiki-org.ru/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC_(%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)) так же есть статья и уже со ссылками на первоисточники.

Собственно на собеседованиях каждый принимающий тестирование понимает под полиморфизмом какой то свой определенный его вид (слава богу мне еще ни разу не говорили, что именно дженерики это полиморфизм). Соответственно на последующих интервью я намерен разводить философию по поводу истинных и не истинных полиморфизмов и выдавать все что знаю, дабы подчеркнуть свое интеллектуальное превосходство, но все же...

Какой из полиморфизмов надо считать полиморфизмом? Понятно, что формально очень много вещей можно отнести к полиморфизму, но что понимают под ним в "простонародии"? Лично я считаю, что это способность использовать ссылку родителя для помещения в нее объекта потомка.
И почему на вики сказано, что дженерики по сути полиморфизм, причем истинный, но никто его в качестве полиморфизма не рассматривает?

Comment: "Не истинный" это тоже всего лишь точка зрения. Если хотите составить собственное мнение - расширьте кругозор, и изучите полиморфизм, например, в Haskell. Там нет полиморфизма подтипов - того Самого полиморфизма из принципов ООП, потому, что там нет ООП. Повернется ли у вас язык после этого назвать "ad-hoc" полиморфизм не настоящим?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почему же никто не рассматривает?

- Параметрический полиморфизм - дженерики.
- Полиморфизм подтипов - ООП-полиморфизм, выражаемый в переопределении методов при наследовании. Same dunction - different behavior.
- Ну и ad-hoc (мнимый полиморфизм) - статический полиморфизм, выражающийся в перегрузке методов.

Наверное, так должен выглядеть стандартный ответ про типы полиморфизма на интервью. Без претензии на разжигание дискуссии и доминирование.